# What is the canonical link function for a Tweedie GLM?

Tags: distributions, generalized-linear-model, tweedie-distribution

I was just introduced to the Tweedie distribution (see [this](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/66859/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_genmod_details28.htm) or [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweedie_distribution)) but I'm having a hard time finding what the link function is for a Tweedie generalized linear model.

Thoughts?

Comment: Why does the first link not answer your question, i.e. what the canonical link is? You can use other link functions as well if they make Interpretation more convenient.

Comment: Is the "canonical parameter" theta in the first link, and the function given afterwards, the canonical link?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At your first link it gives:

$\begin{eqnarray*}  \theta &  = &  \left\{  \begin{array}{ll} \frac{\mu ^{1-p}}{1-p} &  p \neq 1 \\ \log \mu &  p = 1 \\ \end{array} \right. \\ \end{eqnarray*}$

$\frac{\mu ^{1-p}}{1-p}$ is indeed the canonical link function for the Tweedie with power parameter $p$. Often (and equivalently, since it only changes the scale and the Tweedie has a scale parameter) just taken to be $\mu^{1-p}$ when $p\neq 1$.

Check:

- $p=0$ (Normal) $\rightarrow$ identity (yep)
- $p=1$ (Poisson) $\rightarrow$ $\log$ (yep, using the limiting case)
- $p=2$ (Gamma) $\rightarrow$ $-$inverse (yep, though often people just say "inverse")
- $p=3$ (inverse Gaussian) $\rightarrow$ $-$inverse$^2$ (yep, up to a scaling constant;
  $\hspace {5cm}$again, people often just say "inverse squared")

If you need a reference, see Eqn 2.7 of Ohlsson & Johansson (2006)[1]

[1]: OHLSSON, Esbjörn and JOHANSSON, Björn (2006)
   "Exact Credibility and Tweedie Models,"
   *ASTIN Bulletin*, **36**:1,  May, pp 121-133
   DOI: 10.2143/AST.36.1.2014146
   [pdf](http://www.actuaries.org/LIBRARY/ASTIN/vol36no1/121.pdf)